# How properly to get data from form and send GET-request?

Tags: javascript

I have a task to get data from form (three numbers: x, y, r) and send them by GET-request. I understand that it should be done by url, but I don't understand how to the thing right. Here's my not working code:

```js
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("coordinates-form"));
    const sendButt = document.getElementById("submit-button");
    const submit = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("php/get_data.php?x=" + formData.get("x") + "&y=" + formData.get("y")
         + "&r=" + formData.get("r")).then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => document.getElementById('result-table').innerHTML = response);
    };
    sendButt.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

And here's my form in html file:

```html
<form id="coordinates-form">
                <div class="X-radios">
                    <h4>X:</h4>
                    <label class="x-element-label">-3
                        <input class="x_radio" type="radio" name="x" value="-3">
                    </label>
                    // few more radios
                </div>
                <label class="Y-element-label"> Y:
                    <input id="y-text" class="y-text-input" type="text" name="y" placeholder="y value" required/>
                </label>
                <span id="value-validate-text"></span>
                <div class="R-checkboxes" id="R">
                    <h4>R:</h4>
                    <label class="r-element-label">1
                        <input class="r-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="r" value="1" checked>
                    </label>
//few more checkboxes

                </div>
                <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                <button id="clear-button" type="reset">Очистить</button>
            </form>
```

There are parameters in my adress bar (something like .../index.html?x=1&y=1&r=1), but I can not get it by get() method in FormData class. How can I get them and how to do GET-request properly?

Comment: IMO here `fetch("php/get_data.php` you need to use an absolute URL. Beside that, are you sure that the AJAX call actually starts?

Comment: @Andrew no, it actually works this way. The problem was that formData was initialized outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("coordinates-form"));` should have been in submit function.